# What signals histone methyl transferases to function?

Tags: histone, histone-modifications

I wanted to find out if anyone knows what stimulates histone methyltransferases to function?  I know that it is a process still trying to be understood, but I can't find anything that seems to direct the activity of the enzymes.  Additionally, where do the methyl groups come from that the enzymes transfer onto the histones?

Thanks!

Comment: The proximal source of the methyl group is S-adenosyl methionine.

Answer (score 1):

Histone methylation is regulated by a variety of of events, including transcriptional activation and repression, relative location of the histone in the chromatin (pericentric or not, hetero- vs. euchromatin, etc.), X-inactivation, the cell's point in the cell cycle, and others. A variety of signaling pathways can lead to the (in)activation of HMTs. I found this [table](http://www.cellsignal.com/reference/pathway/histone_modification.html#methylation) at cellsignal.com listing known methylation sites, along with literature references. Elsewhere on the site is [this](http://www.cellsignal.com/reference/pathway/Histone_Methylation.html) graphic, which shows some of the same info in a different way, and also has links to data at [PhosphoSitePlus](http://www.phosphosite.org) with links to the protein of interest. If you dig around, you can find all sorts of pathway and experimental information. For example, if you look up [PRMT1 (human)](http://www.phosphosite.org/proteinAction.do?id=6954), you get a brief description of the protein and what pathways it's involved in, as well as links to all sorts of other info. On the histone side, a look at [Histone H4 (human)](http://www.phosphosite.org/proteinAction.do?id=984&showAllSites=true) allows you to look at individual modified residues (I picked K21-m2) and find all sorts of literature links and information about experiments used to determine its function.

PS: I'm not affiliated with Cell Signaling, I just think they have a ton of useful protein information, kind of like NEB for mol bio stuff...